# windows folder for temporary files created by my application

Tags: windows, .net

I'm trying to decide where the 'correct folder' to store documents and logs created by my windows form application.  The application is used in education and has all paths held in the SQL server.  Some (like logs file paths are shared) are accessible on network but specifically for temporary documents where should I default the storage to?  I've recently tried the Users/username/AppData/ folder but I seem to be getting differing results after installation; so far I have put this down to people user credentials as often in schools they can do whatever they want (yes I know shocking indeed).

If anyone can point me in the direction of an MSDn article or knows better please reply - Thanks.

** Edit 10/09/2013 - Sorry all I should be further explicit.  I'm looking for the folder / structure Microsoft has designed for this sort off activity.  My application already provides users with the ability to create thier own working directories (there are several required) but I'm keen to use the 'correct' locations for this sort of activity...  I thought the right place would be c:/Users/USERNAME/Appdata/APPLICATION FOLDER/ but as I mention I've come across a few access rights issues when uses install the application....  hope that explains better - thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a temporary directory in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278439/creating-a-temporary-directory-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

To create temporary directory you can use something like this:

```
public string GetTempDirectory() { 
 string path = Path.GetRandomFileName(); 
 Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), path); 
 Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
 return path; 
}
```

[Path class info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx)
[Directory class info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx)

Comment: And be sure to be polite and delete the temporary file/folders when you are done too.