# Anybody got a good way to ATOMICALLY create a temporary directory in .net managed code?

Tags: c#, .net

The .net framework has GetTempFileName, which goes straight to the Windows API procedure of the same name, and as far as I know is a threadsafe way to create a temporary file with a name not previously in use.  It's hilariously outdated and limited, but as far as I know it works, as long as you keep your temp directory from filling up.

But I don't see anything that'll work even that well for creating temporary folders.  In a contentious parallel environment such as a web server, I don't see any way to avoid race conditions between testing whether a folder name is in use, and creating it.  This could I suppose be doable with unmanaged API code, but there may be institutional resistance to such a solution.  Is there a better way?

And if there is, can it be extended back to temp file creation, so I don't have to use GetTempFileName with its four hex digits of variation?

-- To those who think this is a duplicate: the linked other question did not really address thread safety.  And I have to develop for a situation where thread safety is a very serious concern -- we could have 32 cores running with every one of them attempting to create batches of a hundred or a thousand temp files apiece.

-- UPDATE:  the book *Secure Programming with Static Analysis* by Chess and West says that GetTempFileName “suffers from an inherent underlying race condition”.  So maybe that ain't safe either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a temporary directory in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278439/creating-a-temporary-directory-in-windows)

Comment: If this is a single process on a single server, any reason you don't just generate sequential names atomically using, say `Interlocked.Increment`? Nest them in a clean random directory (create once) if necessary.

Comment: NOT a single process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a unique temporary directory, a combination of [`Path.GetTempPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Guid.NewGuid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) should do the trick quite nicely:

```
string GetUniqueTempPath()
{
    var tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
    var uniqueDirectoryName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var uniqueTempPath = Path.Combine(tempPath, uniqueDirectoryName);

    return uniqueTempPath;
}
```

The fact that a GUID is being used as part of the path should eliminate any race condition as there's *pretty much* no chance that the composite directory name will exist so there's no (real) need to check prior to attempting to create it.

Comment: That would have a high probability of avoiding collisions, I guess, though no guarantee.  But it does give me an idea for the file side of the question, though not the directory side: we can't atomically test-and-set at creation time except with `GetTempFileName`, but it looks like one operation that can do so is `RenameFile`.  So if you create a unique name in the small space that GetTempFileName offers, it can be promoted into the large space offered by GUID names, with guarantee of noncollision, by renaming it.

Comment: (continuing)   That doesn't solve the directory case, though... and if I had threadsafe temp directories, that probably makes the problem of the namespace for files moot anyway, since I don't have to compete for names within my private folder.

Comment: Referring to the documentation for `CoCreateGuid` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms688568.aspx) which is what `Guid.NewGuid` wraps; it states "To a very high degree of certainty, this function returns a unique value – no other invocation, on the same or any other system (networked or not), should return the same value.". In short, you should be collision safe :)

Comment: I'd still feel a lot safer if we had an atomic way to actually test the filesystem, instead of just assuming that with enough entropy there'll probably be no matches there.

Comment: @Paul using GUID should be more than enough but If you are such paranoid about this ,then see this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20483257/1030125

Comment: I'm paranoid because we've had real users encounter real errors from improbable collisions.

Comment: On a further note, I've read that the number of GUIDs per second that a system can create is limited.  This means it's probably safe to use at the directory level but maybe not at the file level.  That's okay, though -- if I'm confident in the directory being distinct, the files inside it can use any old name scheme.

Answer (score 0):

@paul-kienitz FWIW: according to the documentation of [CreateDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya), the function returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if the directory already existed, which gives you an atomic check for collisions. So you can safely create a new temp directory if you combine the random name approach (using `CoCreateGuid()`) with a limited number of retries (e.g. 9 retries), after which you fail. The retries will exponentially lower the collision probability to a value which even satisfies paranoids.