# Create a temporary directory in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, temporary-directory

[PowerShell 5 introduces the `New-TemporaryFile` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-temporaryfile?view=powershell-5.1), which is handy.  How can I do the same thing but instead of a file create a directory?  Is there a `New-TemporaryDirectory` cmdlet?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I think it can be done without looping by using a GUID for the directory name:

```
function New-TemporaryDirectory {
    $parent = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
    [string] $name = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path $parent $name)
}
```

#### Original Attempt With GetRandomFileName

Here's my port of [this C# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/278457/27581):

```
function New-TemporaryDirectory {
    $parent = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
    $name = [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path $parent $name)
}
```

#### Analysis Of Possibility Of Collision

How likely is it that `GetRandomFileName` will return a name that already exists in the temp folder?

- Filenames are returned in the form `XXXXXXXX.XXX` where X can be either a lowercase letter or digit.
- That gives us 36^11 combinations, which in bits is around 2^56
- Invoking the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), we'd expect a collision once we got to around 2^28 items in the folder, which is about 360 million
- [NTFS supports about 2^32 items in a folder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28WS.10%29.aspx#w2k3tr_ntfs_how_dhao), so it is possible to get a collision using `GetRandomFileName`

`NewGuid` on the other hand [can be one of 2^122 possibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29), making collisions all but impossible.

Comment: I'd probably put the `GetRandomFileName()` and `New-Item` in a loop to automatically retry in case of a name conflict.

Comment: @sodawillow Great question. I mistakenly thought you needed `-Force` to create non-existent parent dirs, but I was wrong, so I updated the answer.

Comment: To quote MSDN : *-Force allows the cmdlet to create an item that writes over an existing read-only item. Implementation varies from provider to provider. For more information, see about_Providers. Even using the Force parameter, the cmdlet cannot override security restrictions.*

Comment: If you have 360 million items in your temp folder, I think you have bigger problems than some PS script failing because of a name collision.

Comment: GUID is guarantied to be unique, not  as stated 'unlikely equality'.

Comment: A slightly shorter directory name can be achieved like this: `$name = (New-Guid).ToString('n')`, which creates a string like `450d881de6054d5894c7f7378bbb9f51`.

Comment: If you need to get the folder name so you can use it you need to add a return to the command like this: `Return (New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (Join-Path $parent $name)).FullName`

Answer (score 36):

I also love one-liners, and I'm begging for a downvote here. All I ask is that you put my own vague negative feelings about this into words.

```
New-TemporaryFile | %{ rm $_; mkdir $_ }
```

Depending on the type of purist you are, you can do `%{ mkdir $_-d }`,  leaving placeholder to avoid collisions.

And it's reasonable to stand on `Join-Path $env:TEMP $(New-Guid) | %{ mkdir $_ }` also.

Comment: Seems like a good one-liner to me. Until proven otherwise, I'd assume there's a small chance of a race condition, but that's not a real concern for 99% of use cases.

Comment: Beware, I have seen "delete and recreate" strategies fail on systems with slow anti virus software, as hinted in "The case of the asynchronous copy and delete" by Raymond Chen at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120907-00/?p=6663 .

Comment: Here's the "Native PowerShell" variant: `New-TemporaryFile | % { Remove-Item $_; New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $_ }`

Comment: Adding `-d` doesn't avoid collisions. (What if you're using the same approach in two different scripts at the same time?) But then, you weren't trying to avoid collisions, were you? ;-)

Comment: To clarify, leaving the placeholder is what would avoid collisions (until the commandlet is reimplemented), if they were a risk on practice. The arbitrary deterministic `-d` is to avoid a so-called “collision” between the resulting file and directory.

Comment: Supporting someone else's code is more difficult compared to creating your own.  Sure you can create a dense one-liner.  God help the poor sap trying to understand your intent to support your recommendation.  If your solution is not obvious the likely-hood of a future developer trying to support your code making an error increases substantially.  If the code is obvious and clear the likely-hood of making a mistake decreases.  Some could argue - that is what comments are for, but others will counter-argue the code should be clear enough to negate the need for comments.

Comment: The commands you've provided create the directory, but it neither changes cwd into the dir nor stores the name of the new dir to a variable for future use. Can you please update the answer so the dir is created and also stored to a variable?

Comment: @NathanSchubkegel That's a good point. A character could be appended to the temporary directory name that is being created to avoid a having a naming conflict when the file isn't removed before the directory is created. `New-TemporaryFile | %{ rm $_; mkdir "${_}d" }`.

Comment: I downvoted because of what @MichaelAltfield said... the answer doesn't bother returning the name of the folder.  Sure, it gets created, but I can't _use_ it.  (And you said you were begging for downvotes.)

Answer (score 21):

Here's a variant of user4317867's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570032/165494).  I create a new directory in the user's Windows "*Temp*" folder and make the temp folder path available as a variable (`$tempFolderPath`):

```
$tempFolderPath = Join-Path $Env:Temp $(New-Guid)
New-Item -Type Directory -Path $tempFolderPath | Out-Null
```

Here's the same script available as a one-liner:

```
$tempFolderPath = Join-Path $Env:Temp $(New-Guid); New-Item -Type Directory -Path $tempFolderPath | Out-Null
```

And here's what the fully qualified temp folder path (`$tempFolderPath`) looks like:

```
C:\Users\MassDotNet\AppData\Local\Temp\2ae2dbc4-c709-475b-b762-72108b8ecb9f
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want the looping solution that is guaranteed to be both race- and collision-free, then here it is:

```
function New-TemporaryDirectory {
  $parent = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()
  do {
    $name = [System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()
    $item = New-Item -Path $parent -Name $name -ItemType "directory" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  } while (-not $item)
  return $item.FullName
}
```

According to the analysis in [Michael Kropat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34559554/618906), the vast majority of the time, this will pass only once through the loop. Rarely will it pass twice. Virtually never will it pass three times.

Comment: This won't work, it'll just get stuck in an infinite loop if there is ever a collision... because $name is not updated inside the loop.

Comment: Right, my mistake. I just moved the name creation into the loop.

Comment: Also it'll throw up an unsightly error if it fails for any reason. Also it returns two objects (because New-Item returns an object). Your general approach is sound, but I submitted an edit to your post to fix the issues I found. As far as I can tell, it seems to work. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here's my attempt:

```
function New-TemporaryDirectory {
    $path = Join-Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())

    #if/while path already exists, generate a new path
    while(Test-Path $path)) {
        $path = Join-Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
    }

    #create directory with generated path
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path
}
```

Comment: This code faces a race condition between the end of the `while` and the `New-Item` command.

Comment: @ComFreek, can you explain? Are you talking about when calling this method rapidly in a multi-threaded environment? I don't see how that's possible in a single thread, like a powershell script.

Answer (score 3):

.NET has had `[System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()` for quite a while; you can use this to generate a file (and the capture the name), then create a folder with the same name after deleting the file.

```
$tempfile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();
remove-item $tempfile;
new-item -type directory -path $tempfile;
```

Comment: Where is `$tempfilename` used ?

Comment: Error on my part, I didn't copy/paste my final version. Fixed now.

Comment: This code faces the same race condition [as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41684596/603003).

Answer (score 3):

I love one liners if possible.  @alroc .NET also has `[System.Guid]::NewGuid()`

```
$temp = [System.Guid]::NewGuid();new-item -type directory -Path d:\$temp

Directory: D:\


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                        
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                        
d----          1/2/2016  11:47 AM            9f4ef43a-a72a-4d54-9ba4-87a926906948
```

Comment: This is my favorite. It's clean, and works on Server 2012 R2 era machines. I would probably set $temp direcly with `$temp = New-Item -Type Directory -Path $env:TEMP -Name ([System.Guid]::NewGuid())`

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can be extremely fancy and call Windows API function `GetTempPathA()` like this:

```
# DWORD GetTempPathA(
#   DWORD nBufferLength,
#   LPSTR lpBuffer
# );

$getTempPath = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class getTempPath {
    [DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint = "GetTempPathA")]
    public static extern uint GetTempPath(uint nBufferLength, [Out] StringBuilder lpBuffer);
}
"@

Add-Type $getTempPath

$str = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$MAX_PATH = 260
$catch_res = [getTempPath]::GetTempPath($MAX_PATH, $str)
Write-Host $str.ToString() #echos temp path to STDOUT
# ... continue your code here and create sub folders as you wish ...
```

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha

Comment: This an exact code that `Path.GetTempPath` does  for you internally.

Comment: @martin-prikryl good follow up, do you know how I can view that internal code?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,3a7a8c72321c6e1d,references + Though it will correctly use Unicode version of the API, contrary to your legacy Ansi version.

Answer (score -1):

Expanding from Michael Kropat's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34559554/8083582

```
Function New-TemporaryDirectory {
  $tempDirectoryBase = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath();
  $newTempDirPath = [String]::Empty;
  Do {
    [string] $name = [System.Guid]::NewGuid();
    $newTempDirPath = (Join-Path $tempDirectoryBase $name);
  } While (Test-Path $newTempDirPath);

  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $newTempDirPath;
  Return $newTempDirPath;
}
```

This should eliminate any issues with collisions.

Comment: This code faces a race condition between the end of the `while` and the `New-Item` command, exactly as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34565223/603003) above.